# How to get list of groups that a user follows using chatter rest API

Tags: chatter, chatter-groups

I am new to Salesforce. I am developing an android application for my customer using Salesforce API.

I am required **to display a list of groups that a particular user follows**.But I am not able to find a suitable REST API to accomplish the same.

I have followed read the API documentation over [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/quickreference.htm),but didn't found any API **that will fetch the groups of a user.**

How can I achieve it?
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's GET /chatter/users/userId/groups. Here's the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_users_UserGroups.htm).

Comment: I have just used :RestRequest feedRequest = generateRequest("GET", "chatter/groups", null);
        getGroup(feedRequest);...and it is working ...Thanks for your response anyways